# how to replace dots from 2nd occurrence

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

I have column with software versions. I was trying to remove dot from 2nd occurrence in column, like

`select REGEXP_REPLACE('12.5.7.8', '.','');`

expected out is **12.578**

sample data is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=77240ff766554b20fa9ef222c036f867)

Is it possible to remove dot from 2nd occurrence

Comment: "remove dot after second occurrence" to me implies the result should have 2 dots. Your desired result has 1. Which is correct?

Comment: If your goal is to create something "sortable", then you could also achieve this by converting it into an array `string_to_array('12.5.7.8', '.')::int[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to break this into two pieces:

- Get the first number.
- Get the rest of the numbers as an array.

Then convert the array to a string with no separator and combine with the first:

```
select (split_part('12.5.7.8', '.', 1) || '.' || 
        array_to_string((REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('12.5.7.8', '[.]'))[2:], '')
       )
```

Another option is to replace the first `'.'` with something else, then get rid of the `'.'`s and replace the something else with a `'|'`:

```
select translate(regexp_replace(version, '^([^.]+)[.](.*)$', '\1|\2'), '|.', '.')
from software_version;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9fa0117e2e8f0ac2bbcfd3ed3b3adf34) is a db<>fiddle with the three versions, including the version a_horse_with_no_name mentions in the comment.

Comment: The `regexp_split_to_array()` isn't needed `(string_to_array('12.5.7.8', '.'))[2:]` works as well and is probably faster because no regex is involved

Comment: @GordonLinoff i see 2nd and 3rd version queries are faster than 1st verion query in [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9fa0117e2e8f0ac2bbcfd3ed3b3adf34)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just take the left and right:

```
concat(
  left(str, position('.' in str)), 
  replace(right(str, -position('.' in str)), '.', '')
)
```

For a `str` of `12.34.56.78`, the `left` gives `12.` and the right using a negative position gives `34.56.78` upon which the replace then removes the dots